# Set value for @Html.EditorFor?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

Hi i am trying to set the value for @Html.EditorFor?

Here is my editor:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Customer.CustomerName)
```

And here is how im trying to set it:

```
document.getElementById("CustomerName").value = UserInfo.CustomerName;
```

I get the error message, cannot call method getElementById of undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id of the field is probably like this:

```
document.getElementById("Customer.CustomerName").value = UserInfo.CustomerName;
```

Look at the generated markup to get the real `id` of your input field.

Comment: In your browser. Right click on the page and `View Source`.